# jupyter book WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterbook

- after processing (jupyter-book build) the TOC-navigation does not appear.
- My `_toc.yml` is - at least I think so - according to the [Jupyter Book
  tutorial](https://jupyterbook.org/customize/toc.html).
- The processing information tells: "WARNING: toctree    contains
  reference to nonexisting document". But the source files I    provide
  are processed. In the HTML-view I can find them by using the    local
  search (a Jupyter Book function).
- Beside the source files that are    registered in the TOC, there are
  images that are not registered that are ready to be inserted in the HTML view.
  into the source files. They are inserted correctly after processing, as can be seen.

I am grateful for some debugging ideas! Tx!

**update**

- here is the website without TOC-navigation in GitHub Pages: https://smartoncology.github.io/Manuals-v0.1
- in SEARCH enter: "numpy", and all the "nonexisting documents" will appear
- here  is the repository with all sources: https://github.com/SmartOncology/Manuals-v0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jupyter_book provides support for .md & .rst file by default.

You can use following command to consider specific extension files for toc.

```
jb toc from-project path/to/book/ --extension .ipynb -e .md
```

you can use either `jb` or `jupyter_book`.

Reference link: [customize/toc](https://jupyterbook.org/customize/toc.html#:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20you%20have%20a%20few%20extra%20options%20for%20controlling%20how%20the%20_toc.yml%20file%20is%20generated.)